# Will Xctest launch app on simulator/device on xcode server while doing continuous integration

Tags: ios8, xcode6, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I have set up my mac os server and xcode server and placed my code in repository.i am able to check out and commit my code.Now i have set up my bot which builds the code with my scheme mentioned.

But iam unable to launch my simulator at the server end .where am i going wrong. pls suggest !!

Answer (score 0):

The same issue caused to me i just removed `armv6` support and it started working again and it worked.

Also i would like to recommend you to read [this](http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/24/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory-error.html)

The removal of armv6 support should be here

```
Targets-> Info -> Required Device capabilities and delete the option with armv7
```